# how to create a function that return a value embedded in a record?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a file containing a list of longitudes and latitudes. I'm trying to create a function that will accept a record like the one below. This function will return an uppercase “W” or “E” depending on what is embedded in the record.  That is, w, W, e, or E.

```
DDD MM SS W|E DD MM SS N|S
```

For example:

```
075 45 03 W 45 23 05 N
```

or

```
075 45 03 w 45 23 05 n
```

I'm kind of new with Python coding, so how can I do this?

Thanks for attention!

Comment: To be clear, would your function return `'W'` for both the above examples?

Comment: It depends on the coordinates but for the given example yes function return "w".

Comment: Can you provide more information on what "it depends on the coordinates" means? Also, you used a lower case `"w"` in your comment but an upper case `"W"` in your question. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: So imagine that a list of latitudes or longitudes like "075 45 03 W 45 23 05 N or 076 35 03 E 47 28 05 S". But some entries has lower case w\e. The function will find "E\e" or "w\W" and return uppercase E or W. Does it make sense?

Comment: add more example which contain excepted input/output and unexpected input/output. So it will make people understand easier

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your latitude/longitude entries are always formatted as `DDD MM SS W|E DD MM SS N|S`, you don't need to use regex. You can use simple string indexing as follows:

```
def myfunc(astr):
    return astr[10].upper()
```

This function takes the 10-indexed character in your string (which is `"e"`, `"E"`, `"w"`, or `"W"`) and returns that character in uppercase.

Comment: oh yes. entries are always formatted in same format. I've been trying to create the function with regex and could not solve it out. Thanks for the solution.